# Can a Google Doc share link URL be changed?

Tags: url, google-drive, links, google-docs, sharing

Is it possible to change or regenerate the share URL for a shared Google Docs/Sheets/etc?

For example, it could be useful after having shared it with the "Anyone with the link" option but later wanting to generate a new link to "reset" who has access.

Answer (score 2):

It was possible to reset the link in the older versions, but that feature seems to have been removed. You can, however, make a copy of the document, and that will get a new URL. Remove the old document and use the new copy, and the result will be the same as if you had reset the link.

[image: Make a copy]